# Redux-form - onChange on form not firing

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have problem with using redux-form as a server filter. Purpose of the form is **on every field change send request to server with actual form values** for filtering data in table.

I tried to do it with **onChange event attached to "form"**, then in onChanged event is handleSubmit called. **It works until i used it with my custom Field component**.

When onChanged is used with custom component, then form onChange event is not fired. It is fired only when is normal field "input" edited.

**Is this bug? Are there another ways to submit form after any field change is done?** I tried to do it with formValueSelector but comparing values of form every rerender is not optimal.

Example is here https://codesandbox.io/s/98z3kjk12y

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in custom component, namely that it is `div` - not an element that have `onchange` event. Honestly, it was something new for me that `form` has `onChange` event, but it seems it is fired when any form's child element with `onchange` event is triggered.

If you try to replace in `MyStrangeInput` `div` element with, for example `<input type="text">` `onFormChange` will fired.

<s>As a very, very, very dirty workaround you can customize checkbox with button styles so `onFormChange` will fired(because `checkbox` `onchange` event).</s>

Unfortunately(or fortunately?) `redux-form` doesn't have `handleChange` props, so as i see the most clear solution here will be to call `onFormChange` on each form's field change.

> [Updated example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ojyoo04qjq)

Comment: I was wondering why example in question works like it does. HTML guys really need to start cleaning up the mess with assignable but unused properties, at least by issuing a console warning.